# Data Deleted Successfully bot not updated Automatically in Laravel Vuie JS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

Here is the click event of Manage Category. Here is the remove method that's method working in Vue js code.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="remove(category.id)">Delete</button>
```

Vue JS code is here  Here is a method of remove. When I deleted data it's show notification.

```
<script>
export default {
    name: "manage",
    mounted() {
        this.$store.dispatch("getCategories");

    },
    computed:{
        categories(){
           return this.$store.getters.categories;
        }
    },
    methods:{
        remove: function (id) {
            axios.get("remove-category/" + id)
            .then(function (response) {
                toastr.success("Category deleted Successfully!!");
                this.$store.dispatch("getCategories");


            }).catch(function (error) {

            })


        }

    }
}
```

VUEX cycle is here

```
export default{
state: {

    categoryData:[]
},
getters: {
    categories(state){
       return state.categoryData;
    }

},
actions:{
    getCategories(data){
        axios.get("/get-category")
            .then(function (response) {
                data.commit("categories",response.data.categories);

            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);

        })
    }
},
mutations: {
    categories(state,data){
        return state.categoryData=data;

    }
}
```

}

When I deleted data it is deleted but not remove from the list..  but when I refresh the category list by the computer it's not showing.

Comment: I wanna know that when you delete the category on success is `getCategories` function executing. Can you add a `console.log('getting cat');` to the VUEX `getCategories` function before axios request and check if that console log is outputting when you delete the category.

Comment: I solve it by adding @click.preven="remove(category.id)" just using prevent.